# asp fileExists always returning false

Tags: asp-classic

Trying to use a loop to check if images exists however it is always returning false. I am sure I am doing something simple and stupid but here is the code:

```
dim fs, sql_except
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if Not rs.eof then
    arrRS = rs.GetRows(30,0)
    set rs = nothing
    If IsArray(arrRS) Then
        For i = LBound(arrRS, 2) to UBound(arrRS, 2)
            sku = arrRS(0, i)
            if (fs.FileExists("../i/"&sku&".gif")=false) Then
                response.write sku&"does not exist<br>"
            end if
        next
    end if
    erase arrRS
end if
set fs=nothing
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be operating under the impression that the current folder context the your call to `FileExists` will assume is the physical folder containing the ASP script being executed.  This is not so, it most likely will be "C:\windows\system32\inetsrv".  You are also using URL path element separator `/` where FileExists is expecting windows physical path folder separator `\`.

You need to use `Server.MapPath` to resolve the path.  This *may* work:

```vb
if Not fs.FileExists(Server.MapPath("../i/"&sku&".gif")) then
```

However you may run in to trouble with the parent path "..", this may not be allowed for security reasons.  This might be a better approach:

```vb
Dim path : path = Server.MapPath("/parentFolder/i") & "\"
For i = LBound(arrRS, 2) to UBound(arrRS, 2)        
    sku = arrRS(0, i)        
    if Not fs.FileExists(path & sku & ".gif") Then        
        response.write Server.HTMLEncode(sku) & " does not exist<br>"        
    end if        
next
```

Where "parentFolder" is the absolute path from the site root.